# own MultiMap implementation, problems with put

Tags: java, hashmap, multimap

For the purpose of learning I try to make a MultiMap implementation. (and for avoiding relying on other libraries for a library I make).
It doesn't have to be perfect.

At the moment I have this:

```
class MultiMap<k, v> implements Map {

  HashMap<k, List<v>> hMap = new HashMap<k, List<v>>();  

  public MultiMap () {
  }
```

Followed by all `@Override` methods from `Map`.

One is like this:

```
  @Override
  public Object get(Object o) {
    return hMap.get(o);
  }
```

I have problems with this one:

```
  @Override
  public Object put(Object o, Object o2) {
    // will return a list
    Object toReturn = get(o); 
    if(hMap.containsValue(o)) {
      // is this even possible?
      (List<v>)(List<?>)get(o); // <<< problem: "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"
      // ^ next .add(o2);
    }
    // etc.
    return toReturn;
  }
```

Is it possible to get a List out of the get method?

Answer (score 0):

You define class like this `class MultiMap<k, v> implements Map<k, List<v>>`

and then add new method public `List<v> put(k key, v value)` like that.

```
public List<v> put(k key, v value) {
    List<v> list = get(key);
    if(list == null)
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(value);
    return list;
}
```